# wysiwyg templates for users in django

Tags: python, django, wysiwyg, template-engine

In my web site, there are two kinds of users: Vendors and Customers.

I want the vendors be able to write contract's templates for their customers, for example a Vendor Alice could write:

```
This present contract gives to {{customer_name}} the right to use all the products from Alice's factory.
```

Then, the authorized customers can download (in pdf) their contracts.

I could aks to the Vendor to directly write the templates in the django's template language or use the python string substitution and then give it to reportlab, but:

- the Vendors are not technicians, there are not used to write "code",
- in this way, we can not check easily the errors (e.g., the vendor types {{cutomer_name}} instead of {{customer_name}}),
- I'm afraid about code injection when using django templates (Vendors could be malicious).

Is there any library which implements the functionality I want with a GUI ? For exemple, the Vendors could have a wysiwyg with a button "add customer info" and when this button is clicked, the selected text will be replace by the customer's name during generation.

Comment: I expect you may get closed for asking for a library, but I'm not aware of any library (and I admit it would be nice, especially in context with something like django-cms which might get you closer to having the WYSIWYG portion) ... to try to bound this problem, do you need anything beyond variable substitution (as in loops/includes/math/other things django templates can do)

Comment: No, I only need variable substitution. The vendors are actually not technicians, I don't see me explaining them how a loop works.